# Discord py add role on_message

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been trying to make a command that adds a role to the user when he/she speaks in a specific channel. Then the role mutes the user making it a one message channel.

**Code:**

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.name == '・message-archive':
        await client.process_commands(message)
    elif "" in message.content:
        role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="one message")
        await message.author.add_roles(role)
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

The problem is that it adds a role in ANY channel. I want it to be used only on 1 channel.

I've tried using `if` and `else if` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check if the name/ID of the channel is the correct one:

```py
if channel.id == 182739817283172:
    await message.author.add_roles(role)
```

```py
if channel.name == "whatever":
   await message.author.add_roles(role)
```